# Selecting right click option from context menu in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a scenario where i need to right click on a link, when context menu appears i need to click on option "Open link in incognito window".
When i try to achieve this by below code snippet i could see a context menu appears but instead of launching the link in new window the link gets launched in same window.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.linkText("About"));
action.contextClick(ele).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

any suggestions how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a keyboard shortcut for opening a link in an incognito window but I was unable to find one but I didn't look for long. You may have better luck.

Another method would be to grab the URL of the link you want to click, open an incognito window using the keyboard shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+N), and then navigating to the URL. It's not ideal but I don't know of another way to do this.

Is there some reason you can't just start your script in an incognito window and proceed from there?

Comment: I have a scenario where I need to open two windows/tabs by clicking on a link from parent window and perform some operation simultaneously in both windows using driver.switchTo(). i'm trying to open that window in incognito just to make sure browser sessions are different

Answer (score 0):

This context menu is not a part of html page, but this is a menu coming from Chrome  (a desktop application)
Selenium/WebDriver does not have the capability to automate the desktop applications, you can use AutoIt or similar software to do it
But all what you need is just to open a new browser session (incognito window is nothing but a new, independent browser session).
To simulate this behaviour using WebDriver just open a new Chrome driver:

```
WebDriver drv1 = new ChromeDriver();

drv1.get("https://www.google.pl");
drv1.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("About");
........
........

// This will open a new browser window with a new, independent browser session
WebDriver drv2 = new ChromeDriver();
drv2.get("https://www.google.pl");
drv2.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello");   
........
........
drv1.do-Something-in-session-1
.....
drv2.do-Something-other-in-session-2
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i always had option to create another webDriver session but i don't want to that since this particular scenario is needed for only couple of tests. but thanks for your pointer that the context menu is from window i thought it is from browser and is part of DOM.

Comment: Even if you automate this menu using an externall tool, for example AutoIt, then a new browser window will open outside of WebDriver, Selenium will not know that session and will not be able to handle it.

Comment: ohh is it? any other option you can think of?